# Ansible - ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set

Tags: ansible

I've an error when I launch a playbook but I don't found why....

> ERROR! the field 'hosts' is required but was not set

There is my main.yml :

```
---
- hosts: hosts
- vars: 
  - elasticsearch_java_home: /usr/lib/jmv/jre-1.7.0
  - elasticsearch_http_port: 8443

- tasks: 
  - include: tasks/main.yml

- handlers:
  - include: handlers/main.yml
```

And my /etc/ansible/hosts :

```
[hosts]
10.23.108.182
10.23.108.183
10.23.108.184
10.23.108.185
```

When I test a ping, all is good :

```
[root@poste08-08-00 elasticsearch]# ansible hosts -m ping
10.23.108.183 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong" }
10.23.108.182 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong" }
10.23.108.185 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong" }
10.23.108.184 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong" }
```

Please, help me :)
Regards,

Comment: What happens if you change the name of the `hosts` group, for example to `instances`?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your playbook.

```
---
- hosts: webservers
  vars:
    http_port: 80
    max_clients: 200
```

See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_intro.html

Comment: to put it another way, everything needs to be indented under "hosts", not at the same level.

Comment: Thank you, it was a mistake in my playbook.

Comment: You're welcome. Would be grat if you can mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
---
- hosts: all

  remote_user: root

  tasks:
```

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. Should have a space between the hyphen and any declaration that follows. e.g. - hosts: all

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this in future, for me this was as I didn't  have the hosts: line above tasks / pre_tasks. Moving it up fixed the issue...

Comment: In my case, I simply forgot to include a `hosts: ...` line in my playbook. Adding it fixed the issue

Answer (score -2):

Remove hyphen sign before task since this is the part of single play:

```
---
hosts: hosts
- vars: 
  - elasticsearch_java_home: /usr/lib/jmv/jre-1.7.0
  - elasticsearch_http_port: 8443

- tasks: 
  - include: tasks/main.yml

- handlers:
  - include: handlers/main.yml
```

According to the [YAML spec](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/#id2489726):

> Block sequences indicate each member with a dash (“-”). Block mappings use a colon to mark each (key: value) pair.